# Cloud Firestore document read cost for subcollections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to calculate firestore cost? I know that it count every operation, but if I read one document that contain sub collection how it count?

For example, If I read "A Document" that has 1 "Sub-Collection B" and "Sub-Collection B" have 5 document. Then how much it could if I only read "A Document", it will count 1 or 5 operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The location of a document has no bearing on the billing for its reads.  It could be in a collection, or a subcollection, or a subcollection of a subcollection - it just doesn't matter.  One document read always costs the same.

Comment: I just discovered that I am being charged for using the Firebase console. I filtered and bam, an extra 7000 reads.

Comment: Doug, can I ask for clarification on your answer?  I understand that it doesn't matter *where* the document is -- but what about if the document itself contains collections with their own documents?  Then, **when you read the master document, have you implicitly read all of the documents in its subcollections, too?**

Comment: No, queries are always shallow and don't touch subcollections.